# Append a number to a variable name in GDScript

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'd like to append an integer to the end of several variable names in GDSCript.

I'm working on a roguelike and I've decided to organise themed tilesets and NPC's and group them in folders by number (ie, theme 1 may be a crypt filled with undead, theme 2 a forest filled with animals).
The idea is that at the start of level generation I can randomly select a number, generate a level and fill it with corresponding enemies.

For example (assuming the random number is 1)

```
tileset_to_use = tileset_1
NPC_mid_boss = folder_1/mid_boss
NPC_end_boss = folder_1/end_boss
```

Aside from a series of nested IF statements along the lines of:

```
if RNG = 1:
    tileset_to_use = tileset_1
    NPC_mid_boss = folder_1/mid_boss
    NPC_end_boss = folder_1/end_boss
elif RNG = 2:   
    tileset_to_use = tileset_2
    etc...
```

...what would be a more efficient way of doing this? Something like tileset+RNG
I've looked into using dictionaries but, unless I've misunderstood them, they seem to be used for accessing values rather than generating variable names.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but doesn't Godot support multiple scenes and scene instances for purposes such as this? Might you try saving your tilemaps as different scenes, and calling them at random when generating the level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your themes share the same exact structure, you can do something similar to [what Christopher Bennett proposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55938499/1782792). Another option that may give you more flexibility, at the expense of possibly more repetition, is something like this:

```
# Defined at class level
const THEMES = [
    # Theme 1
    {
        tileset = 'tileset_1',
        NPC_mid_boss = 'folder_1/mid_boss',
        NPC_end_boss = 'folder_1/end_boss',
        # ...
    },
    # Theme 2
    {
        tileset = 'tileset_2',
        NPC_mid_boss = 'folder_2/mid_boss',
        NPC_end_boss = 'folder_2/end_boss',
        # ...
    },
    # ...
]


func my_func():
    # Pick a random theme
    var theme = THEMES[randi() % THEMES.size()]
    tileset_to_use = theme.tileset
    # ...
```

This also allows you to add more properties like arbitrary strings (e.g. theme name) or other things, and can be externalized to something like a [JSON document](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_jsonparseresult.html) if you want. But again, it requires more manual setup.

Comment: I also like this solution - take your pick ;)

Comment: Thank to both of you, this solution is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question when I posted my first comment. Would something like this work?

```
var RNG = randi()%1-(total number of tilesets); 
var tileset_to_use = (str("tileset_",RNG));  
    NPC_mid_boss = (str("folder_",RNG,"/mid_boss"));
```

Comment: Or is the problem that you want the result to be a non-string. In this case, you're better off to use a dictionary. Make the dictionary `var dictionary={1:tileset1, 2:tileset2,3:tileset3}`. Then set variable `RNG=i` and search the dictionary with  `for i in range(0-dictionary.size()): var tileset=dictionary[i]`. Then you can set `var tileset_to_use = tileset`.